# NoSuchElementException while launching an OSGI framework

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have created Maven based project in which I am tring to launch an OSGi container(Felix) by using the below code but everytime, it is giving me below exception-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$ServiceIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:187)
    at com.ebay.personalization.osgi.test.osgitest.App.main(App.java:28)
```

Below is my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BundleException, IOException {

        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("felix-cache"));
        FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();

        Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(new HashMap<String, String>());
        framework.start();

        BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();
        List<Bundle> installedBundles = new LinkedList<Bundle>();

        installedBundles.add(context.installBundle("C:\\Store\\TestingModel-1.0.0.jar"));

        for (Bundle bundle : installedBundles) {
            bundle.start();
        }

        ServiceReference reference = context.getServiceReference(ITestService.class.getName());
        ITestService service = (ITestService) context.getService(reference);
        service.speak();
    }
}
```

As soon as I run the above code, I always get the above mentioned exception-

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.host.domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>DomainParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- POM Information about the Project -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.host.personalization.osgi.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>OsgiTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <!-- Packing Type is bundle for OSGI Library Bundle -->
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.url</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-url-mvn</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build Configration -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Apache Felix Bundle Plugin - For Generation of Manifest after Compile 
                phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Configuration for generating the Manifest.mf -->
                <configuration>
                    <manifestLocation>src/main/resources/META-INF</manifestLocation>
                    <!-- Manifest Headers which need to customized during manifest generation -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>OsgiTest</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Configuration of repositories for dependency resolution -->
    <repositories>
        <!-- domain Bundles Repository -->
        <!-- This is needed to locate the domain Parent project. Other repositories 
            come from the parent. -->
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://nxdomain/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>thirdparty</id>
            <url>http://nxdomain/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
            <releases>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Can anybody tell me what wrong I am doing here? I know ServiceLoader searches the FrameworkFactory interface in the classpath and if it is not able to find then it will throw an exception. But in my case, I already have an dependency on felix framework so it should be there in my classpath.. Right? Then what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Is apache felix framework on your classpath?

Comment: If I am adding a maven dependency of felix framework in my pom.xml file. Then it won't go into my classpath?

Comment: Before closing the question. Please see that question, in that also, they are saying to add the felix framework in classpath. But I already have felix framework in my classpath.. Dont be in so hurry in closing the post.

Comment: Did you see the answer and the comments in that clearly? It clearly says, maven dependency won't help. Try to add the Bundles to classpath, and see if it works.

Comment: I have already done that as well. By adding jar file in the classpath using buildpath. But no luck..

Comment: No you have not done that. You need to put Felix on the **runtime** classpath. This is NOT the "build path" and it has nothing to do with Maven or the sodding POM. I'm voting to close this question since it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Neil:Thanks Neil. Any suggestion how can I put Felix on the runtime classpath?

Comment: When you run your application, add Felix to the list of JARs/directories that you specify with `-classpath`. The Felix framework JAR can be downloaded from http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi